# QGIS set default style for layers based on name

Tags: qgis, raster, style

I know that it is possible to apply default fill/line/point and colour ramp styles for layers within a project, However...

I have a model which spits out raster layers with defined names (e.g. NAME_XXXX_wd).  I don't want to apply a colour ramp but instead an actual style file.  Is it possible to set up a project that would automatically apply a style file to an added raster layer based on the name and how might you do it?

I'd also be happy to select the layer in the TOC and hit a toolbar button but would prefer something completely automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be fully automatic but you could run a function in your **Python Console** which loads a style file from a specified folder with the same name as your raster. Insert the following code into the console:

```
def run(name):
    # Change path accordingly
    style_path = 'C:/Users/You/Desktop/Style_Folder/' + name + '.qml'
    for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
            if name in layer.name():
                layer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)
                layer.triggerRepaint()
                qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

Now when you want to add a style file to a raster called "NAME-XXXX", type the following in the console (*note the single quotation marks*):

```
run('NAME')
```

This searches for a style file called "NAME" and if any layer includes the word "NAME" in their actual name, then the style file will be applied.

Comment: Tip: You can do `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName()` to just get the layers with the matching name without the loop.

Comment: Ooh that is tantalisingly close.  Is it capable of doing wildcards?  For example my rasters are called NAME-XXXX where the XXXX is an iterating number so could it be set up to search just for a name stub?

Comment: @NathanW - Pro tip from a pro! Will try and implement that into the script ;)

Comment: @EdRollason - Made a slight edit to the code which should now check to see if the style name is used in the layer name =)

Comment: That works well thanks - I'll leave it open for 24hr to see if anyone suggests anything else and then I'll mark it answered.  Now i should look at implementing it as a plugin I guess!